# <AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting this error, I tried adding a redirect_to() and return to my access_doc_or_redirect() method, but no luck.  Any recommendations?

```
 def access_doc_or_redirect(doc_id, msg)
   doc = Document.find(params[:id])
   if doc.user_access?(current_user)
     @document = doc
   else
     flash[:alert] = msg
     redirect_to root_url and return
   end
 end

 def get
   access_doc_or_redirect(params[:id], "Sorry, no document view access.")
   redirect_to @document.file.url
 end
```

### Error

access_doc_or_redirect(params[:id], "Sorry, no document view access" AbstractController::DoubleRenderError: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.

Error is self descriptive you are calling render or redirect multiple times in your action. Lets look at your methods:

```
def access_doc_or_redirect(doc_id, msg)
  doc = Document.find(params[:id])
  if doc.user_access?(current_user)
    @document = doc  
    #this block will run fine and return @document to get method
  else
    flash[:alert] = msg
    redirect_to root_url and return
    #this block is giving you trouble because you are redirecting to root url and then control goes back to your get method where you are using redirect again and hence double render error
  end
end
```

**FIX:**

If you are using it as a filter then to fix error you can do:

```
def get
  #i think this is your main method so you should use redirect or render inside this method only
  #instance variables set inside access_doc_or_redirect will automatically be available inside this method
  if @document 
    redirect_to @document.file.url
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Sorry, no document view access."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end

def access_doc_or_redirect
  @doc = Document.find(params[:id])
  if @doc.user_access?(current_user)
    @document = doc
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is I'm trying to keep the code DRY and keep the access_doc_or_redirect as a before_filter.  Why does "and return" not work?

Comment: @user2012677 as i explained in my answer by using return it'll return out of access_doc_or_redirect method and control will go to get method and you are using redirect there again and hence your error

Comment: how can I redirect and "END" then?

Comment: @user2012677 updated my answer i think this is the best you can do also since **get method is the main method in your case and other one is only a filter so it makes sense to redirect inside get method**